# Suggestion on path to take: Coredata vs NSDefault

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I'm currently trying to decide between using `CoreData` vs `NSUserDefaults`.  I'm trying to store two arrays and be able to delete and write to them.  From my research, `NSUserDefaults` only allows `NSArray`s, meaning that I cannot change them once they are created. However, I think that a way to get around this would be to simply save all the data from the array, delete it, and then resave it as a new array. Thoughts?

Comment: Choosing between `NSUserDefaults` (which is what I assume you mean by NSDefault) and Core Data should be a simple one. `NSUserDefaults` is meant to store small pieces of data like user preferences. Core Data is a data base system meant to manage large amounts of data. If you have just a few strings to save, then use `NSUserDefaults`. If you have a large set of data to maintain, then you Core Data. If you have something in between, then look into plists or JSON files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 options to save data

- NSUSerDefault
- File System
- Core Data

**NSUSerDefault**

Is designed for storing user preference data. It's a key-value storage. This is not a safe place and it's very easy to get access to it. Don't store any sensitive data here.

**File System**

Very simple and flexible data storage. You can use [NScoding](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) to save custom object to files. NSArray has a method for saving its object to a file
[NSArray writeToFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:)

**Core Data**

Core data is a database. It is most complex and powerful data storage of all 3 options. It allows you t create a data base scheme, models, run queries and do other stuff.

## Answer

In your case I would choose **File System**, save data to a file.

**Swift 1.2**

```
let documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let filePath = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("file.plist")

let array: NSArray = [1, 2, 3]

let res = array.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
let array2 = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```

**Swift 2.0**
`stringByAppendingPathComponent` is deprecated in Swift 2.0
There is a better API to work with paths using `FileManager` and `NSURL`

```
let documents = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentationDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let fileUrl = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("file.plist")

let array: NSArray = [1, 2, 3]

let res = array.writeToURL(fileUrl, atomically: true)
let array2 = NSArray(contentsOfURL: fileUrl)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Just to clarify in order to rewrite the array I would simply set array to the new value?  Also is file.plist the file where the array is stored?

Comment: yes it's store in the file.plist in document directory. To rewrite the data, just call save once again, it will replace content of the file

Comment: Hey Kostiantyn would it be possible for you to update this for Swift 2.0?  I've spent the last day trying to convert it with no luck.  Thank you!

Comment: hi @SnarfSnarf I've added Swift 2.0 Example

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the purpose of `NSUserDefault` is just like the **Setting** app from your iDevice. It's used for storing some setting data rather than as a database. Due to its dictionary like syntax, there are many developers use it for storing small pieces of data conveniently rather than storing setting data which is suggested from Apple. The design of `NSUserDefault` is not for handling heavy I/O so that you can't treat it as a normal database to use. Based on the above points, you can choose what to use based on your need.